# Is the Time Complexity of this function O(n * (n * log n² ))

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, notation

What is the Time Complexity of the function below? n > 0

```
Function fun(n){
    Let count = 0;

    For( I = 0; I < n; I++){

        For(j = 0; j < n; j /= 2) {

            For(h = 0; h < n; h /= 2) {

                Count = count + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    Return count;
}
```

I have O(n * (n * log n² )) , but something tells me i might be wrong.

Comment: It's definitely more than quadratic. Do you need to be particular precise?

Comment: Note that `log(n^2)` is basically `log(n)`.

Comment: @mangusta I suspect that the two inner loops have the wrong bounds.  Once fixed, your comment is right.

Comment: ok, to avoid confusion: if the OP implies `j*=2` and `h*=2` loop updates instead of `j/=2` and `h/=2` then the complexity is `O(n * logn * logn)`

Answer (score 2):

The above loop is an infinite loop. time complexity for this cannot be determined, unless the problem statement is updated properly!

```
Function fun(n){
    Let count = 0;

    For( I = 0; I < n; I++){
        // will run infinitely even if you change j /= 2 to j *= 2, because initial value is 0
        For(j = 0; j < n; j /= 2) {
            // will run infinitely even if you change h /= 2 to h *= 2, because initial value is 0
            For(h = 0; h < n; h /= 2) {

                Count = count + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    Return count;
}
```

Comment: Why is this an infinite loop?

Comment: @gue, Because zero when divided by anything results in zero. So, as per the 2nd loop, when the initial value of j is zero, and it is divided  by  two will result in zero. Hence the condition j<n will always be satisfied.

Comment: You are right. My mistake. (I can only undo my downvote if you edit, sorry.)

Comment: Oh my.  My mistake.  I was so focused on something else, but for others it is very true that there aren't many examples of big o functions where you divide by a number every iteration, because if n is 100 and j < n, but you divide j by ANYTHING that is positive it will never equal 100 and be infinite.  My apologies.